# React: How to submit a form with <textarea> with enter key and without a submit button with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs

Halo guys I am quite new to react and I want to submit a form with only a text area with `enter` key press. I followed some of the SO questions but still no luck as it is not getting submitted. I also want to clear the text area after the submit. How can I do it with the below code?

This is the code I currently have.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();

const CommentOnSubmit = (data) => {
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('content', data.content);
    formData.append('user', user?.id);

    axiosInstance.post(`api/blogs/` + slug + `/comment/`, formData);
} ;

// const commentEnterSubmit = (e) => {
//     if(e.key === 'Enter' && e.shiftKey == false) {
//         return(
//             e.preventDefault(),
//             CommentOnSubmit()
//         )
//     }
//   }

<form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(CommentOnSubmit)}>
                <div className="post_comment_input">
                    <textarea
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Write a comment..."
                        name="content"
                        ref={register({required: true, maxLength: 1000})}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="comment_post_button">
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">comment</Button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Please do help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use React [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) `onKeyPress` like this:

```
   <textarea
          type="text"
          placeholder="Write a comment..."
          onKeyPress={ commentEnterSubmit}
          name="content"
          ref={register({ required: true, maxLength: 1000 })}
        />
```

**UPDATE**
In your *commentEnterSubmit* function:

```
 const commentEnterSubmit = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && e.shiftKey == false) {
      const data = {content:e.target.value};
      return handleSubmit(CommentOnSubmit(data));
    }
```

And if you want to reset your input you can use the `setValue` from `useForm` hooks.
like this:
add setValue to  `const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors,setValue } = useForm();`

```
 const CommentOnSubmit = (data) => {
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("content", data);
    formData.append("user", user?.id);
// your axios call ...
    setValue("content","");
  };
```

I have made a code [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-maxwell-24lhw?file=/src/form.js) based on your example

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I tried this but its showing an error `cannot read property content of undefined`.

Comment: I think the issue is due to your data params that is undefined

Comment: This is the error.
`cannot read property "content" of undefined`

Comment: I am able to submit the form with the button though.

Comment: pass e.target.value to:   `const commentEnterSubmit = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && e.shiftKey == false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return CommentOnSubmit(e.target.value);
    }
  };`
[sand](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-maxwell-24lhw?file=/src/form.js:449-619)

Comment: Tried it, the form is getting submitted without errors, but in the database, the content is showing as undefined rather than the typed comment.

Comment: Yes, it works great. Thanks a lot.
can you tell me how to clear the field after submitting?

Comment: You're welcome , I've updated my answer for the reset feature.

Comment: People reading this now should use the event listener on the textarea as `onKeyDown` now, as `onKeyPress` is now deprecated.